# WinDbg session does not connect

Tags: windows, driver, windbg

I have followed the lab [Debug Windows drivers step-by-step lab (echo kernel mode)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debug-universal-drivers---step-by-step-lab--echo-kernel-mode-).

Once I come at point 8 in which I reboot the target and it should connect to the host, nothing happen.

Below the `bcdedit /enum all` result on target.

```
Firmware Boot Manager
---------------------
identifier              {fwbootmgr}
displayorder            {bootmgr}
                        {3b372d9e-b8b8-11ed-9af1-806e6f6e6963}
                        {8b84a908-a37d-11ed-9aed-806e6f6e6963}
timeout                 1

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
path                    \EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {7e7d0076-9117-11ed-a6ff-a7cd5c734c1b}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Firmware Application (101fffff)
-------------------------------
identifier              {3b372d9e-b8b8-11ed-9af1-806e6f6e6963}
description             UEFI: PXE IPv4 Intel(R) Ethernet Controller (3) I225-LM

Firmware Application (101fffff)
-------------------------------
identifier              {8b84a908-a37d-11ed-9aed-806e6f6e6963}
description             UEFI: PXE IPv6 Intel(R) Ethernet Controller (3) I225-LM

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 11
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {7e7d0078-9117-11ed-a6ff-a7cd5c734c1b}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         Yes
testsigning             Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {7e7d0076-9117-11ed-a6ff-a7cd5c734c1b}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
debug                   Yes

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {7e7d0078-9117-11ed-a6ff-a7cd5c734c1b}
device                  ramdisk=[\Device\HarddiskVolume4]\Recovery\WindowsRE\Winre.wim,{7e7d0079-9117-11ed-a6ff-a7cd5c734c1b}
path                    \windows\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows Recovery Environment
locale                  en-us
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
displaymessage          Recovery
osdevice                ramdisk=[\Device\HarddiskVolume4]\Recovery\WindowsRE\Winre.wim,{7e7d0079-9117-11ed-a6ff-a7cd5c734c1b}
systemroot              \windows
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
winpe                   Yes

Resume from Hibernate
---------------------
identifier              {7e7d0076-9117-11ed-a6ff-a7cd5c734c1b}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winresume.efi
description             Windows Resume Application
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {resumeloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {7e7d0078-9117-11ed-a6ff-a7cd5c734c1b}
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
filedevice              partition=C:
custom:21000026         partition=C:
filepath                \hiberfil.sys
bootmenupolicy          Standard
debugoptionenabled      Yes

Windows Memory Tester
---------------------
identifier              {memdiag}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\memtest.efi
description             Windows Memory Diagnostic
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
badmemoryaccess         Yes

EMS Settings
------------
identifier              {emssettings}
bootems                 No

Debugger Settings
-----------------
identifier              {dbgsettings}
key                     2steg4fzbj2sz.23418vzkd4ko3.1g34ou07z4pev.1sp3yo9yz874p
debugtype               NET
hostip                  192.168.0.183
port                    50000
dhcp                    Yes

RAM Defects
-----------
identifier              {badmemory}

Global Settings
---------------
identifier              {globalsettings}
inherit                 {dbgsettings}
                        {emssettings}
                        {badmemory}

Boot Loader Settings
--------------------
identifier              {bootloadersettings}
inherit                 {globalsettings}
                        {hypervisorsettings}

Hypervisor Settings
-------------------
identifier              {hypervisorsettings}
hypervisordebugtype     Serial
hypervisordebugport     1
hypervisorbaudrate      115200

Resume Loader Settings
----------------------
identifier              {resumeloadersettings}
inherit                 {globalsettings}

Device options
--------------
identifier              {7e7d0079-9117-11ed-a6ff-a7cd5c734c1b}
description             Windows Recovery
ramdisksdidevice        partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume4
ramdisksdipath          \Recovery\WindowsRE\boot.sdi
```

The host IP address 192.168.0.183 is correct and I disabled the Windows firewall. I have also checked the key but everything seems to be correct.

Comment: Are both machines physical machines? Do both machines can ping each other? Have you also tried to check what [`kdnet.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/setting-up-a-network-debugging-connection-automatically) says about your NIC? Some NICs are not supported for network debugging or require to correctly set up  the `busparams`.  DHCP can sometime be a PITA, depending on your network configuration (in which case I would assign static IPs to both machines and set target's dbgsetting dhcp to "no").

Comment: Thank you Neitsa. KDNET tells me "Network debugging is not supported", even if I have a Intel network card (I255LM). I have to find another machine for the target.

Comment: I have checked on a second PC where the kdnet says that the NIC is compatible. Disabled the secure boot and assigned static IP to target and host but it still does not connect. The only difference with the lab is that both PC are running Windows 11 and not Windows 10.